# Python line by line execution

Tags: python, dwg, fme

I couldn't fine solution for this question using search option so my question is:
I have a script that does the job but only for one file. Just to explain what`s going on here:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\FME\fmeobjects\python27')

import fmeobjects 
runner = fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner()
workspace = 'C:\FME\Project_1.fmw'

parameters = {}
parameters['SourceDataset_ACAD'] ='C:\AutoCAD\Project_1.dwg'
parameters['DestDataset_OGCKML'] ='C:\Maps_KMZ\Project_1.kmz'  
runner.runWithParameters(workspace, parameters)

try:
    # Run Workspace with parameters set in above directory
    runner.runWithParameters(workspace, parameters)
    # or use promptRun to prompt for published parameters
    #runner.promptRun(workspace)
except fmeobjects.FMEException as ex:
    # Print out FME Exception if workspace failed
    print ex.message
else:
    #Tell user the workspace ran
    print('The Workspace is ran successfully'.format(workspace))

runner = None
```

This script executes FMW file that does conversion from AutoCAD DWG  (C:\AutoCAD) to KMZ file and stores it in C:\Maps_KMZ folder. Now, I need to do the same thing for about 20-ish FME files that are in the same source folder. 
Is it possible to  execute each file at the time and add specific time frame between two executions let`s say 2 minute pause between them,  because I can not run 2 or more conversions at the same time, it would crash Windows.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Put the file paths in a list, put the processing in a function, iterate over the list and pass the filepath(s) to the function, put a delay at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Notice how @wwii describes the steps in words. I suggest you flesh out his suggestions in more detail primarily using English, or whichever language you are most comfortable with. When you have a good verbal description of the steps needed to solve the problem then you can start to translate it into Python.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you modify your script to use command line arguments. You can either use `sys.argv` directly for a very simple interface or the `parseargs` module for more complex options.

You can write the interface to accept individual files names or directory names. To traverse the files of a directory, look at `os.walk()`.

Comment: or the `click` library for a simple interface *and* complex options :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not familiar with click. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick replies ..... the problem is that I have no much Python experience.

Comment: I suggest you google "python command line arguments" or "python parseargs" to find some documentation and tutorials.

Comment: "the problem is that I have no much Python experience" From my point of view, that is an opportunity, not a problem.

Comment: As a computer programmer and software engineer, learning to read technical documentation is critical. After you have done some reading, then Stack Overflow is a great resource to ask questions about the parts that are confusing. Just be sure to ask specific questions, including quotes from your reading that you do not understand.